# Se reinicia mi input tipo fecha

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos me gustaría saber si alguien sabe por que al yo modificar un div que contiene un input tipo date el valor de la fecha que tenia guardado se reinicia.
Por ejemplo tengo este input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando le selecciono una fecha y presiono el botón test, la fecha que seleccione se borra.

Este es el código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="prueba" class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type="datetime-local"></input>
            <button onclick="test();" type="button" >test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function test() {document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML += '<button>PRUEBA</button>';}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si me pudieran explicar por que sucede o me dieran una solución se los agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: @cooper la función esta ahí, es la linea gigante a la derecha

Comment: Ahí esta, en la etiqueta script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo en el innerHTML es que estas sumandole el botton y luego lo asignas al innerHTML, recuerda que el operador += toma el valor actual (valor inicial) de la variable, suma con la segunda variable y la asigna a la variable actual (valor inicial), por eso se resetea.

En resumen estas haciendo esto :

```
innerHTML = '<input><button1>' + '<Button2>'
```

Te recomiendo utilices esta función

```
function test() {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Prueba";
    document.getElementById('prueba').appendChild(button);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que debes corregir tu función primero que nada...
No se si realmente quieres estar creando botones de este modo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo otro, es cambiar esta parte:

```
function test() {document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML += '<button>PRUEBA</button>';}
```

Por esto:

```
function test() {let button = document.createElement("button"); button.innerHTML = "Prueba"; document.getElementById('prueba').appendChild(button);}
```

Comment: Es solo una función de prueba, ese error me apareció en otro programa e hice este para pedir ayuda, por cierto muchísimas gracias c:

Comment: ohh jajaj esta bien entonces